# Format floats in Django template in language aware manner

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates

I am using Django's [humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#ref-contrib-humanize) to make large float numbers in my app more readable. Also my app is available in different languages, and different languages use , and . signs in numbers the other way around.

For integer values the humanize tag `intcomma` works well:

```
{{ intvalue|intcomma }}
```

Would give for different locales:

```
English:  1,000,000
Dutch:    1.000.000
```

However, using floats this doesn't work very well. For example in my template you would find this:

```
{{ floatvalue|floatformat:2|intcomma }}
```

Would give for different locales:

```
English:  1,000,000.00
Dutch:    1,000,000,00
```

Note that instead of 1.000.000,00 for Dutch, it shows 1,000,000,00. Switching around the floatformat:2 and intcomma tags doesn't work either as then the value is nothing.

**Any ideas on how to easily fix this?**

(If possible, I'd rather not use an external libraries such as [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Try the Django [**Format Localization** feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/). It gives you three options. As the Django docs say,

> Django’s formatting system is capable to display dates, times and numbers in templates using the format specified for the current locale. It also handles localized input in forms.
>
> When it’s enabled, two users accessing the same content may see dates, times and numbers formatted in different ways, depending on the formats for their current locale.
>
> The formatting system is disabled by default. To enable it, it’s necessary to set `USE_L10N = True` in your settings file.

Thus this first option turns on locale-dependent number formatting for all of your templates.

A second option is to use the [`localize` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#localize) to turn on locale-dependent number formatting for only part of a template. For example,

```
{% load l10n %}

{% localize on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

A third option is to use the [`localize` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#std%3atemplatefilter-localize) to force locale-dependent number formatting for a single value. For example,

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ value|localize }}
```